# how to use the package wordnet in R?

Tags: r, wordnet

I try to install `wordnet` in R.

I already use `install.packages("worddnet")` but I can check from my package even if I type `library(wordnet)`.

Someone can help? (y)

Comment: are you really trying to install "worddnet", or do you mean "wordnet"?

Comment: i mean "wordnet".

Answer (score 1):

After downloading and installing 'wordnet.exe' in your computer, library(wordnet) will work

The file is downloadible in the website :  http://wordnet.princeton.edu/wordnet/download/current-version/#win